# Switching regulator component on Raspberry Pi 4 fallen off

Tags: pi-4

I lost the component lables KE 8J617 on my Raspberry 4

Do you know where I can get that component or what the name of that is (did a google search on the KE 8J617, that showed nothing)

[image: Component]

Cheers!

Comment: Ah let me see. It is just a cap, C84 in the schematic: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/104596/rpi3b-micro-usb-connector-got-15v-power-is-it-dead-can-i-save-it.

Comment: You can get a complete set of replacement parts for ONLY $35

Comment: And BTW, are you sure MAX7704 is switching anything?

Comment: Thanks all. looks like its a 3216 47uF SMD capacitor. I'll give it a try. Its a 4GB Pi-4 that costs here in NZ over $NZ100, so worth while to give it a try, instead of buying a new one.

Answer (score 3):

It is a TVS diode.

"A transient-voltage-suppression (TVS) diode, also transil or thyrector, is an electronic component used to protect electronics from voltage spikes induced on connected wires." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transient-voltage-suppression_diode

https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/stmicroelectronics/SMBJ5.0A-TR/497-3144-1-ND/654464