# Raspberry Pi 3B fell to the ground, "4R7" box looks busted. Is dead?

Tags: hardware, pi-3b+

I was toying around with the Pi, left it in a place where I should have not put it, and it fell to the ground. I picked it up again and noticed one of the small "4R7" labeled boxes was kind of busted (in a 90 degree angle with the board).

I've tried to plug it on and is not working. No lights, no boot, nothing. It seems everything is pointing towards the Pi being dead. Am I right?

EDIT: This is how it looks:

[image]

Comment: I forgot what is 4R7. Let me check my old photos to refresh my memory: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/104596/rpi3b-micro-usb-connector-got-15v-power-is-it-dead-can-i-save-it.

Comment: The black box marked R47, might be the 47uF capacitor to bypass the noise of the power supply. Usually without the capacitor the power supply can still work, but noisy. . to continue, ...If you can find the two terminals, you can extract two wires and solder an external one, like what I did with the fried polyfuse. But I am only 10% sure of what I am talking. ***Warning***: I am just a friendly hobbyist. No guarantee no nothing won't melt down or blow up. Good luck and cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like one of the inductors - if you get yourself a schematic there are two - L1 and L2 that are 4.7uH, both used to provide the internal voltage rails, 3.3V and 1.8V from the 5V supply so unless you are able to refit a new one I afraid that it is probably broken.

Comment: As far as DIY repairs go, this is a pretty easy one. A broken inductor can easily be removed using a heat gun or two soldering irons on the sides.

Comment: Yeah, I consulted some other friends and it seems this is the case. Thanks. I have zero knowledge of the hardware part, and I'm more interested in having a Pi working again, so I guess I'll get a new one and leave this for future repairs once (and if) I can learn about it.