# Raspberry Pi 3B MF-MSMF250/X Polyfuse

Tags: pi-3

In the schematic diagram here https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/rpi3/raspberry-pi-3-b-reduced-schematics.pdf there is MF-MSMF250/X polyfuse. What will happen if the polyfuse get damaged for some reason? Is Raspberry Pi 3B will still function?

Comment: depends on the damage

Comment: this might help: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/104596/rpi3b-micro-usb-connector-got-15v-power-is-it-dead-can-i-save-it/104614#104614