# raspberry pi 3b+ suspected polyfuse problem

Tags: pi-3

Well, then I was just using my pi 3b+, but suddenly it stopped working, and there was only the red light, but not the green light. I tried many sd cards, but it still didn't work. and I found out that when I touch the Polyfuse of RPI3B+, the red light goes out and then I thought "is it a Polyfuse problem or something?". Well I'm really not that good using raspberry pi or with engineering/programming and there's no way to buy a new RPI because where I live there's none of them or it's just really expensive.

Raspberry pi 3B+
32gb SanDisk Ultra SD card
5v 3amp Power supply (non-oficial)

i would be very appreciated if someone could help me, real thanks!

Comment: have you considered that the power supply is failing?

Comment: If you suspect it is the polyfuse problem, and after you have tried all troubleshooting ways, you can try the final trick: ***replacing the polyfuse***. Ref: 
Rpi3B+ micro USB connector got 15V power. Is it dead? Can I save it? Asked 2 years, 10 months ago Modified 2 years, 4 months ago Viewed 1k times
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/104596/rpi3b-micro-usb-connector-got-15v-power-is-it-dead-can-i-save-it/104614#104614

Comment: right, i will see what can i do for the Polyfuse. thanks for the respond!